# generalising nested calls to map with a function

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a good way to define function `map-nest` that perform nested mapping operations that can be customised by an extra nesting value:

```clj
(map-nest 0 inc [1 2 3 4 5])
; 0th LEVEL
; expands to (map inc [1 2 3 4 5])
=> '(2 3 4 5 6)

(map-nest 1 inc [[1 2 3] [4 5]])
; 1st LEVEL
; expands to (map (fn [x] (map inc x)) [[1 2 3] [4 5]])
=> '((2 3 4) (5 6))  

(map-nest 2 inc [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5]]])
; 2nd LEVEL
; expands to
; (map (fn [y] (map (fn [x] (map inc x)) y))
;      [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5]]])
=> '(((2 3) (4 5)) ((6)))

; and so on
;
```

is there a good way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be some recursive mapping function, maybe something like this:

```
(defn map-nest [level f data]
  (let [f (if (zero? level) f (partial map-nest (dec level) f))]
    (map f data)))

user> (map-nest 0 inc [1 2 3 4 5])
;;=> (2 3 4 5 6)

user> (map-nest 1 inc [[1 2 3] [4 5]])
;;=> ((2 3 4) (5 6))

user> (map-nest 2 inc [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5]]])
;;=> (((2 3) (4 5)) ((6)))
```

You could also think of nested mappings as a reductions stream, where each starting from the function, producing the one next level mapping on every iteration:

```
(defn make-nested-mappers [f]
  (rest (iterate #(partial map %) f)))

(defn map-nest [level f data]
  ((nth (make-nested-mappers f) level) data))
```

Comment: `(defn map-nest [n f coll] ((reduce #(partial %2 %1) f (repeat n map)) coll))`